# Организация сортировок по различным параметрам класса Java

Tags: java

Есть список с объектами. Необходимо от различной ситуации отсортировать данный список по разным значением полей класса. 
Пример:

```
 public static void doSort(List<Mix> array, int start, int end, int type) {
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    int i = start, j = end;
    int cur = i - (i - j) / 2;
    while (i < j) {
        switch (type) {
            case 1: {
                while (i < cur && (array.get(i).getCost() <= array.get(cur).getCost())) {
                    i++;
                }
                while (j > cur && (array.get(cur).getCost() <= array.get(j).getCost())) {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                while (i < cur && (array.get(i).getBaseCost() <= array.get(cur).getBaseCost())) {
                    i++;
                }
                while (j > cur && (array.get(cur).getMaxSpeed() <= array.get(j).getMaxSpeed())) {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            Collections.swap(array,i,j);
            if (i == cur)
                cur = j;
            else if (j == cur)
                cur = i;
        }
    }
    doSort(array, start, cur, type);
    doSort(array, cur+1, end, type);
}
```

В зависимость от переданного параметра производится сортировка по тому или иному полю, выбор поля производится с помощью switch.

Можно ли уйти от switch? Организовать сортировки более гибче(через параметризованный метод, перегрузку) в данном случае?

Comment: Передавайте нужный компаратор просто

Comment: @iksuy, можно пример или источник для чтения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно создать необходимые `Comparator`-ы и использовать нужный в конкретной ситуации:

```
private static class Element
{
    private final int
            cost,
            baseCost,
            speed;

    public Element(int cost, int baseCost, int speed)
    {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.baseCost = baseCost;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getCost() { return cost; }

    public int getBaseCost() { return baseCost; }

    public int getSpeed() { return speed; }

    public String toString() { return "{" + cost + " " + baseCost + " " + speed + "}"; }
}

private static final Comparator<Element> comparatorElementCost =
        (Element e1, Element e2) -> (e1.getCost() - e2.getCost());

private static final Comparator<Element> comparatorElementBaseCost = 
        (Element e1, Element e2) -> (e1.getBaseCost() - e2.getBaseCost());

private static final Comparator<Element> comparatorElementSpeedCost =
        (Element e1, Element e2) -> (e1.getSpeed() - e2.getSpeed());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Element> list = Arrays.asList(new Element(1, 20, 300), new Element(2, 10, 200), new Element(3, 30, 100));
    list.sort(comparatorElementCost);
    System.out.println(list);
    list.sort(comparatorElementBaseCost);
    System.out.println(list);
    list.sort(comparatorElementSpeedCost);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Также можно создать нужный comparator c помощью метода `Comparator.comparing`:

```
private static final Comparator<Element> comparatorElementCost =
        Comparator.comparing(Element::getCost);
```

Если не предполагается часто использовать comparator, то можно и не выносить его в переменную:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Element::getCost));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно также не создавая `Comparator`-ы с помощью Java 8 Stream API

```
public class B {
    String s;
    Long i;

    public B() {
        s = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        i = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public Long getI() {
        return i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    B b1 = new B();
    Thread.sleep(222L);
    B b2 = new B();

    List<B> list = Arrays.asList(b2,b1,b2,b1,b2,b1);

    List<B> sSort = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getS())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<B> iSort = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getI())).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, comparator при этом всё же создаётся. Просто он не присваивается в переменную, а сразу передаётся в метод.