# Как сделать сложную сортировку с помощью Comparable

Tags: java

Есть список содержащий ФИО,оценку по русскому,оценку по математике,оценку по физике. Мне нужно отсортировать студентов от лучшего к худшему по 3 критериям: максимальная сумма баллов, затем с большим баллом по математике, затем по физике(сначала проверяет по сумме баллов, если будут одинаковые суммы , то уже проверяет баллы по математике, а если по математике одинаковые оценки , то проверяет по физике)
Например:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add((new Student("Сергуй","Сергуй","Сергуй",3,5,2))); //1 оценка-русский,2-математика,3-физ
list.add((new Student("Кирилл","Кирилл","Кирилл",4,2,4)));
list.add((new Student("Дмитрий","Дмитрий","Дмитрий",5,4,3)));
list.add((new Student("Саня","Саня","Саня",2,3,5)));
```

Должно получиться : Дмитрий, Сергуй, Саня, Кирилл

Есть класс student для описания каждого из студентов:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    String SecondName;
    String FirstName;
    String Othestvo;
    int RussianMark;
    int MathMark;
    int PhysicMark;
    int TotalMark;



    public Student(String SecondName, String FirstName, String Othestvo, int RussianMark, int MathMark, int PhysicMark) {
        this.SecondName = SecondName;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.Othestvo = Othestvo;

        this.RussianMark = RussianMark;
        this.MathMark = MathMark;
        this.PhysicMark = PhysicMark;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return SecondName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        SecondName = secondName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getOthestvo() {
        return Othestvo;
    }

    public void setOthestvo(String othestvo) {
        Othestvo = othestvo;
    }

    public int getRussianMark() {
        return RussianMark;
    }

    public void setRussianMark(int russianMark) {
        RussianMark = russianMark;
    }

    public int getMathMark() {
        return MathMark;
    }

    public void setMathMark(int mathMark) {
        MathMark = mathMark;
    }

    public int getPhysicMark() {
        return PhysicMark;
    }

    public void setPhysicMark(int physicMark) {
        PhysicMark = physicMark;
    }

    public int getTotalMark() {
        return RussianMark + MathMark + PhysicMark;
    }

    public void setTotalMark(int totalMark) {
        TotalMark = totalMark;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student) {
        if(MathMark == student.getMathMark()){
            return 0;
        }
        if(MathMark < student.getMathMark()){
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

У меня получилось сделать сортировку по математике(см последние строчки в классе).Но сделать сортировку с учетом всех критериев не получается, буду рад если поможете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Организация сортировок по различным параметрам класса Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639803/%d0%9e%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы реализовать логику сравнения, воспользуйтесь статическим методом `Integer.compare` сравнения двух чисел:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    int c1 = Integer.compare(other.getTotalMark(), this.getTotalMark());
    if (c1 != 0) return c1;
    int c2 = Integer.compare(other.getMathMark(), this.getMathMark());
    if (c2 != 0) return c2;
    return Integer.compare(other.getPhysicMark(), this.getPhysicMark());
}
```

Отсортировать список можно с помощью `Collections.sort`:

```java
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

Можете использовать методы интерфейса Comparator для более удобного описания условия сравнения объектов

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student student) {
    return Comparator.comparing(Student::getTotalMark)
            .thenComparing(Student::getMathMark)
            .thenComparing(Student::getPhysicMark)
            .reversed()
            .compare(this, student);
}
```

Похожая конструкция также используется для определения алгоритма сравнения (например в методах Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c), List.sort(Comparator c)), если класс не реализует интерфейс Comparable либо логика приложения подразумевает несколько вариантов алгоритмов сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать интегральную оценку как взвешенную сумму произведений баллов, по которой и производить сравнение. Веса соответствуют значимости оценок, например, "всего" умножаем на 100, математику на 10, физику на 1:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student student) {
            return Integer.compare(student.getTotalMark() * 100 + student.getMathMark() * 10 + student.getPhysicMark(), getTotalMark() * 100 + getMathMark() * 10 + getPhysicMark());
        }

@Override
public String toString() {
            return getSecondName() + ": " + getTotalMark() + ", " + getMathMark() + ", " + getPhysicMark();
        }
```

После сортировки

```
list.sort(Student::compareTo);

[Дмитрий: 12, 4, 3, Сергуй: 10, 5, 2, Саня: 10, 3, 5, Кирилл: 10, 2, 4]
```